# Why does Perl's sysopen report success but $! has an error?

Tags: perl

My sysopen fails:

```
sysopen(DEV, "/dev/ttyS0", O_NONBLOCK|O_RDONLY)
```

returns 1, which is a success! Then, why does $! have the error "Illegal seek" in it (where it is undef before the call)

```
before sysopen $!:
after sysopen $!: Illegal seek
```

EDIT:
Here is the full script: (using the actual O_NONBLOCK|O_RDONLY value 2048)

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use Device::SerialPort;
 my $ob;

 $ob = new Device::SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0");

 print $!, "\n";
 $! = 0;

 my $ret = sysopen(DEV, "/dev/ttyS0", 2048);

 print $!, "\n";
 $! = 0;

 print "ret from sysopen: ", $ret, "\n";
 #my $dev = <DEV>;
```

which prints out:
./filehandle.pl
Illegal seek
Illegal seek
ret from sysopen: 1

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour for `sysopen my $ttyh, '/dev/ttyS0', O_NONBLOCK|O_RDONLY or die "Cannot open tty: $!";` ?

Comment: Always post complete demonstration scripts. Isolated lines of code don't show the problem you create.

Comment: Ether - I got the same error with your suggestion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's how the C `errno` variable works.  To quote from [`man errno`](http://man.cx/errno):

> Its value is  significant only when
>   the return value
>   of the  call indicated an  error (i.e., -1 from  most system
>   calls; -1  or NULL from most library  functions); a function
>   that succeeds *is* allowed to change `errno`.

[`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ERRNO) is just Perl's interface to `errno`, and has the [same behavior](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ERRNO):

> This means that the value of `$!` is
>   meaningful only *immediately* after a
>   **failure**

You must check the return value of `sysopen` to determine whether it failed.  If it failed, `$!` will tell you *why* it failed, but you can't use `$!` to determine *whether* it failed (unless the particular function you're using is documented to set `$!` to 0 on success.  Most don't, including `sysopen`).

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! i was really struggling with it all day

Answer (score 1):

Many similar special variables in Perl don't change their value until they have to. You always should check for the condition that would actually set the variable. Two of the most common examples are resetting error variables when there is an error or resetting regex capture variables on a successful match.

```
 unless( sysopen( ... ) ) {
      die "Error was $!";
      }

 if( m/(...)(...)/ ) {
      print "Found $1 and $2\n";
      }
```

This is certainly one of Perl's warts since it relies on side effects of distant global variables to denote what happened locally. It's even a bit worse in some cases because something else can change the special variable before you get a chance to look at it so you always should inspect it immediately before running any other statements.

Comment: That's not really his problem here.  It's not that he's checking it too late, and something else changed it.  It's that a function that succeeds can still set `$!` to some non-empty value, but that does **not** indicate that the function failed.

Comment: The solution is the same though. Only look at it under the conditions that would set it to an interesting value. It's a general best practice.

Comment: I was trying to use it as an error checking method...thank you for the info it helps A LOT. (I edited my orig post with the full script like you wanted)